# GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException when creating a project with symfony 2.8 framework

Tags: php, symfony

First of all i created the **symfony file** through the following cmd :

```
php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"
```

After that, i performed the following command to create a symfony project :

```
php symfony new my_project 2.8
```

The result :

**[GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate**

So, is there a solution to this problem ?

Comment: what is the OS? windows?

Comment: I use Windows 7 and within it Wamp as a solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Download cacert.pem file from here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
2. Save the file in your PHP installation folder. ( ex D:\wamp\php\cacert.pem).
3. Open your php.ini file and add this line:
   curl.cainfo="D:\wamp\php\cacert.pem"
4. Restart your Apache server